# Using web API within bot command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have an API server running on what listens to http://localhost:8089/ModAPI/?q=online&a=somerandomstring, where `q=` is the command and `a=` the API key. I am able to open this from outside.

I want this info to be called by a discord bot with a command like `!online`; how can I get this done? I literally have no clue.
It should print as text.
Someone told me that you have to do it with a `GET` request. That's where I'm stuck. I can't find the right code for it. Either it's with JSON parsing what doesn't work. Or I can't even start my bot. Anyone who knows the right code? I want it to be able to be called with `!online`, then it should post the text from my link.

[API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sY2X.png)

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
console.log('Ready!');
});
var request = require('request');

request('http://IP:PORT/ModAPI/?q=online&a=KEY', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', body);// Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
});
client.login('TOKEM');
```

If but it responds to console :( If i try to add a command to get it called on i cant even start it. I dont know how to finish it

Comment: See [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: No one who can help me out?

Answer (score -5):

I recommend that you check out the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) **Node** package and attempt to use that with your server. It is a really great package for **GET** requests.

Comment: This should be a comment. If you want to post an answer then you should fix the OPs code using the library you're suggesting and explain specifically how it does what the OP needs it to do.

Comment: Sorry about that; did not mean to post an **Answer**.

Comment: @Gisgar3 you can delete and post that as a comment.

Comment: I have the request package. thing is i dont know anything about codeing. ive tried to search different things up and they all fail when i try it out :(. I need some pointers in the right direction to get the code actually